# How to check if a time is before a interval using joda time

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to see if a given Date-time happens before a specific time.

If it does then return `true` else `false`

Let D be a time from  before S
Let S be limit of our time frame. 
Let F be the time that is after S.

> D---------------------D-S------- F

So D will return true and F will return false as input to this problem

```
Interval time = new Interval(schenduledDepature, schenduledDepature)

if (time.getEnd().isBefore(aDate)) return true
else return false
```

For some reason this doesn't work, I always get false even when it's before the time frame. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the how you are acquiring `aDate` — Joda's `.getEnd()` returns a Joda `DateTime` and that compares with an _instant_, milliseconds before the epoch. Depending how you get `aDate` you might not be comparing what you think you are comparing. (By the way, you _never_ have to do `if (someCondition) return true; else return false;` that is _always_ the same as `return (someCondition)`. For you, that would be `return time.getEnd().isBefore(aDate);`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [doc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableInterval.html#isBefore(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)):

> Is this time interval before the specified instant.
>   Intervals are inclusive of the start instant and exclusive of the end.

Because the start and end of the `Interval` are the same, you get always false.
Create the `Interval` with a difference between them, making sure `aDate` is in between, and try again.

P.S - instead of using `if-else`, just `return time.getEnd().isBefore(aDate)`.

Comment: Good catch! I hadn't noticed that `schenduledDepature` was used for both the start _and the end_ of the interval. But this begs the question -- why is Dave using an Interval at all? Why not an Instant or a plain-old Date?